# Sharepoint Online (O365) Custom List - Auto-Expire/Delete

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am developing a custom solution that uploads data into a SharePoint (Online/O365) custom list using a custom .Net application (using SharePoint REST/XML/Web services).

As part of company's GDPR/Data Retention policy, entries in the list need to be removed after a certain period based on a specific date field (+ retention policy) in the list entry.

The retention period would like only be for about 21days from creation date to expiry date and the list itself wont actually contain too many rows... in the 100s, rather than 1,000s if that makes any difference.

The actual expiry date can be calculated by the uploading application if that helps so there could be a field called "expiry" if needed.

Can SharePoint Online do this automatically or do I have a) write a script/app; b) have some sort of "workflow" or c) purchase some add-in (3rd party or MS)

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the list settings, there's a link for "Information Management Policy Settings".

In there, you can select policies for "Items".

You'll see a checkbox for "Enable Retention" and a link will appear under it where you can specify what your retention schedule is and what to do when that is met.

So in your case, you'd select "creation date + 21 days" and the action will be to delete the item.

Comment: Thanks... Will give that a go

Comment: Initial setup didn't appear to do anything but I am still very new to SP Online so it might be something I did .. I will have another look in the near future .. its not something top of my list right now though